# How to use Grub loader to dual boot windows and Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

1. I have 1st installed windows7 on my Levona Z570 laptop.
2. Later Installed Ubuntu 14.04 on it.
3. After Ubuntu installation, I have updated ubuntu and installed Grub loader2 customzer.
4. Now after restart ,there is no windows7 at boot nor any grub customizer in ubuntu.
   I have attached the log link.please help me to dual boot.
   http://paste.ubuntu.com/22567278/

Comment: Anyone who attempts dual booting without reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI is doomed to confusion, failure and frustration.

Comment: You can try to [repair grub from a live usb](http://askubuntu.com/a/88432/498541) hoping that it will detect the OS and fix everything.

Comment: Have you run `sudo update-grub` ? You show a newer UEFI system, but both Windows & Ubuntu installed in BIOS/CSM/Legacy boot mode. If still not working try Boot-Repair's advanced mode and the full uninstall/reinstall of grub (that will remove Customizer also as it adds its own grub files).